# HDEV Goodbye Video- similar projects planned?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, communication, power, earth-observation, hdev

I just found that nice "Goodbye HDEV" video on the Columbus-Eye-Projekt-Webpage. (http://columbuseye.rub.de/)

Seems like the HDEV-housing is already burned during re-entry.

Does anyone know if they are similar projects planned for the future?

HDEV was able to deliver so much stunning footage, but I was a bit disappointed about the quick end. The EHDC (External High Definition Camera) is no proper replacement for the videos that were made by the 4 HDEV-cameras.

I would love to see some FullHD or even 4K cameras up there on the ISS, streaming almost 24/7 like HDEV.

Are there any technical problems like a high streaming rate (to the earth) or constant energy supply that would make such a project impossible?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I hadn't seen the video of the payload being removed from the trunk and installed, pretty cool.